# ¿como conectar android a mysql (BD externa)?

Tags: android, sql

Amigos estoy creando una app y necesito consultar datos de mi host, por lo que he leido hasta el momento esta obsoleto usar la libreria apache httpcient ahora debo usar hilos, no lo se estoy perdido, alguna ayuda o tutorial. de ante mano gracias!!! y ojo es mi primera pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Robin. Por favor explica el contexto y escenario sobre el que trabajas. ¿Acaso deseas conectarte a tu base de datos directo desde tu aplicación móvil o a través de servicios? Si es a través de servicios, ¿tu consulta se orienta hacia cómo consumir esos servicios puesto que HttpClient fue depreciado por Google para Android 6.0?

Comment: Muchas gracias luiggi. Si efectivamente quiero hacerlo a traves de servicios para ello intento hacerlo con AsyncHttpClient; estoy usando libreria jloop pero aun no puedo resolver el problema.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que la forma más segura y escalable es ofrecer una API de servicios en un servidor y sea este último que se conecte a la base de datos.

- Más segura porque no es recomendable dejar el puerto a la base de datos abierto.
- Más escalable porque en un servidor contarás con más recursos para resolver las solicitudes de los clientes de la API.

También podrás consumir la API desde otro tipo de cliente como por ejemplo, un sitio web.

Actualmente estoy en el desarrollo de una aplicación que se conecta a una base de datos MySQL y desde Android utilizo **retrofit2** para consumir la API y el servidor lo estamos desarrollando con **nodejs** utilizando el modulo **node-mysql**.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.

Comment: Hola, bueno creo que eso es mucho mas profesional y me diste el pie para indagar sobre API.   Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a la clase para conexión [**org.apache.http.client.HttpClient**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) como comentas, es actualmente obsoleta, si aún requieres usar la clase [`HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), puedes agregar esta dependencia en tu `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Aunque lo recomendable es usar la clase [**HttpURLConnection**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.htm) si tu target es Android 2.3 o superior (lo cual seguramente es así).

Ejemplo:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

#### Para conectar a una base de datos externa, lo realizas mediante un [Servicio Web](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servicio_web) (`Web Service`):

Este es un tutorial en español de una aplicación Android, que consume un `Web Service` usando HttpURLConnection, espero te sea de ayuda:

**[Consumir Web Service en Android de una manera sencilla](http://www.ejemplosprogramacion.co/index.php/articulos/articulo/consumir-web-service-en-android-de-una-manera-sencilla/)**

Comment: Elenasys , muchas gracias ! lo revisare

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, coincido con la respuesta hecha por Pablo, lo mejor es que crees tus servicios restfull. Si usas PHP puedes usar Sublime que te ayudara a crear un servicio restfull rápidamente. También he tenido la oportunidad de usar retrofit2 con rxjava. https://medium.com/@ahmedrizwan/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff#.7trimxrhd Es muy útil a la hora de conservar el valor de una petición a tu servicio.Saludos

Comment: Tocayo, muchas gracias !!!

Comment: De nada Tocayo! jejeje

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimado yo te recomendaría que usaras la librería Volley que es la librería oficial de google(Android) para hacer peticiones a servidor de mysql a través de php generando xml, a mi me sirvió lo usé para conectarme a una Bd Mysql, para consultar datos y a la vez hacer modificaciones (Insert, Update) te dejo un link para que veas un tuto que me sirvió: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/