# Conexión a mysql en Android

Tags: android, mysql

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en android la cual se tiene que conectar a una base de datos en mysql que se encuentra en un servidor ,dicho servidor no tiene salida a otras redes ,todo es dentro de la empresa.

la aplicación tiene que poderse conectar desde cualquier punto,sin importar si esta dentro de la misma red o no.

esto es posible y de ser así alguien sabe que debo investigar?

Comment: Si la base de datos no es accesible desde fuera de la red de la empresa, tu aplicación android no podrá comunicarse con ella desde fuera de la red.

Comment: sabes si existe alguna manera de que  la base de datos sea accesible desde afuera?

Comment: Como explican aldakur una solución es utilizar una `conexión vpn` aquí tienes un link que pueder serte útil http://www.androidpit.es/vpn-como-se-configura

Comment: Este enlace también es interesante: http://www.xatakandroid.com/sistema-operativo/como-configurar-y-para-que-sirve-usar-una-vpn-en-android

Comment: Necesitas exponer una conexión a tu servidor para poder acceder al servicio desde fuera, investia sobre API's y Tunel VPN.

Comment: En este caso te traigo un link de 4 partes que te especificara como se debe de conectar android a la base de datos:
Parte 1:
http://picarcodigo.blogspot.mx/2014/05/webservice-conexiones-base-de-datos.html
Parte 2:
http://picarcodigo.blogspot.mx/2014/05/webservice-conexion-base-de-datos-mysql.html
Parte 3: http://picarcodigo.blogspot.mx/2014/05/webservice-conexiones-mysql-desde.html
Parte 4: http://picarcodigo.blogspot.mx/2014/05/webservice-conexion-base-de-datos-mysql_14.html

Answer (score 2):

Mediante una `conexión VPN` debería de ser posible. Hay muchas aplicaciones para realizar las conexiones VPNs en android. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vpn&hl=es

Answer (score 0):

Si tu base de datos únicamente es visible en tu intranet es obvio que no podría conectarse cuando tu aplicación se encuentra en otra red.

Primeramente tienes que hacer visible tu base de datos para que puedas realizar una conexión remota.

Primeramente necesitas subir tu base de datos a un web server

http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1212.php

y posteriormente realizar una conexión remota a la base de datos MySQL.

http://www.cafetero100.info/2011/12/06/como-me-conecto-via-remota-a-una-base-de-datos-mysql/

Comment: Hola ,muchas gracias, solo una duda, si en la empresa cuentan con un programa a nivel intranet y de ese programa se hacen las inserciones de base de datos locamente. lo que ellos quieren es ver las incersiones desde cualquier lugar , pero es posible hacer eso, es decir si yo subo la base de datos al web server aun podre seguir viendo e insertando datos de manera local y ver los cambios en el servidor web ?

Comment: Regularmente en lugar de varias aplicaciones leer una bd, se usa como intermedio un WebService el cual realiza el trabajo de insertar/obtener los datos http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8164/95